# Graph coloring upper bound

Tags: graph, discrete-mathematics, graph-coloring

Wikipedia states for graph coloring the following upperbound:

[image: X(G)*(X(G) - 1) = 2 * #edges]

But I don't understand why this is. The give. Information is unclear to me.

Someone who can help me?

Comment: if there is anything that you dont understand from my answer please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Bounds_on_the_chromatic_number) it is so clear,by the way the sentence is

> In an optimal coloring there must be at least one of the graph’s m
>   edges between every pair of color classes

I'll break it down and make every part more clear.

- **In an optimal coloring** : this means that you found a coloring in graph that you cant reduce any more color from it, and if you reduce one color there will be two similar color neighbors.
- **must be at least one of the graph’s `m` edges between every pair of color classes** : Consider the optimal coloring from the first part, it there was two colors for example `A` and `B` that there is no edge between `A` colored nodes and `B` colored nodes(*unlike this statement*) then we could change colors of all the `A` colored nodes to color `B`, but it is a contradiction from the first statement.
- **From first two statement we have the formula** :

  - we have `X(G)(X(G) - 1)/2` pairs of color in this coloring.
  - there is at least one edge between all this pairs.
  - so we have `X(G)(X(G) - 1) /2` less than equals `m` so we have :

[image]